# How do you overload apply in trait?

Tags: scala

Consider the following code in scala  https://scastie.scala-lang.org/xmJEm5YoTfujUnQbAnycDg

```
      trait MyFactory[Record] {

        def apply(
          paramInt: Int
        ): MyBuilder[Record]

        def apply(
          paramInt: Int,
          paramString: String
        ): MyBuilder[Record] = {
          // DO something with string
          // doesn't work with MyFactory[Record](paramInt) also
          return MyFactory(paramInt)
        }
      }

      object MyFactory {
        
      }

      class MyBuilder[Record] {
        
      }
```

I am expecting that I can implement default `apply` for one of the overloading function and call the other, but compiler is complaining `object MyFactory in object Playground does not take parameters` which confuses me because the `trait` does have `apply` taking parameters, and I see `default method` work in the official doc https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/traits-abstract-mixins.html for trait, so I am confuse why it can't find the correct overloading function

```
trait TailWagger {
    def startTail(): Unit = println("tail is wagging")
    def stopTail(): Unit = println("tail is stopped")
}
```

I assume the compiler will look at the trait to see the correct `apply` to use

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't use `return` in Scala!

Comment: sorry , i am new in scala, why don't you want to use return in scala?

Comment: See https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/05/09/return.html, it's not doing what you think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just do this?

```
return apply(paramInt)
```

The error is because you are trying to call `apply` on the companion object which doesn't have an `apply` method. The `apply` in the trait can only be called on an instance of the trait because it is a method of that trait.

Comment: Without `return` it I'll be even better :)